# replace array value in php in non associative array

Tags: php, arrays

replace array value in php in non associative array,so that the output will be  `$arr = array(1,3,4,5);` I want to replace today with 1.

How to replace 'today' with 1?

```
$arr = array('today',3,4,5);
```

Comment: 1. Have you tried something ? 2. Why 1? and not 0 or 2 ?

Comment: It is my requirement,i want to replace 'today' with given  value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write like this code below

```
$arr = array('today', 3, 4, 5);
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
  if ($value == 'today') {
    $arr[$key] = 1;
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: @Manoj I think a more inflexible solution you couldn't get

Answer (score 2):

Find key of 'today' by array_search

```
$arr[array_search('today', $arr ,true )] = 1;
```

Comment: @Manoj If you know that there will: 1. Always be a `today` value and 2.Only ever be just one `today` value, then this should be should be your accepted answer.  This is because `array_search()` ceases to iterate the array as soon as the `needle` value is found.  Viswanath's answer does not employ this "best practice".  Though you are not required to, you can help future SO readers to find the best method by awarding the green tick to this answer. p.s. If either of #1 or #2 are not guaranteed, then a full-iteration method would be justifiable -- but I don't get this sense from your question.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

First I filter all elements out, which aren't numeric with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). Then I get the keys from them with [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

After this I [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) an array with the `$keys` and a [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) from 1 to [as many keys you have].

At the end I just simply replace the keys which haven't a numeric value with the number of the `$fill` array with [`array_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php).

```
<?php

    $arr = array('today', 3, 4, 5);
    $keys = array_keys(array_filter($arr, function($v){
        return !is_numeric($v);
    }));

    $fill = array_combine($keys, range(1, count($keys)));
    $newArray = array_replace($arr, $fill);
    print_r($newArray);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 5
)
```